# Is there a way I can pass the result of a route as a field in another route?

Tags: javascript, express, multer, cloudinary

I am trying to upload an image with multer to cloudinary and then store the resulting url in a database column. I have the following code:

The cloudinary config file:

```
import { config, uploader } from 'cloudinary'
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
const cloudinaryConfig = (req, res, next) => {
config({
cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});
next();
}
export { cloudinaryConfig, uploader };
```

The multer config file:

```
import multer from 'multer';
import Datauri from 'datauri';
import path from 'path';
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const multerUploads = multer({ storage }).single('image');
const dUri = new Datauri();

/**
* @description This function converts the buffer to data url
* @param {Object} req containing the field object
* @returns {String} The data url from the string buffer
*/

const dataUri = req => dUri.format(path.extname(req.file.originalname).toString(), req.file.buffer);
export { multerUploads, dataUri };
```

The entry point file(app.js)

```
import express from 'express';
import { urlencoded, json } from 'body-parser';
import { resolve } from  'path';
import { uploader, cloudinaryConfig } from './config/cloudinaryConfig'
import { multerUploads, dataUri } from './middlewares/multerUpload';
const app = express();
const Port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.static(resolve(__dirname, 'src/public')));
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(json());
app.use('*', cloudinaryConfig);

**app.post('/upload', multerUploads, (req, res) => {**
if(req.file) {
const file = dataUri(req).content;
return uploader.upload(file).then((result) => {
const image = result.url;
return res.status(200).json({
messge: 'Your image has been uploaded successfully to cloudinary',
data: {
image
}
})
}).catch((err) => res.status(400).json({
messge: 'something went wrong while processing your request',
data: {
err
}
}))
}
});
app.listen(Port, () => console.log(`Server started at http://localhost:${Port}`));
```

I have tried to split the functions and call them in the application routes but req.file was undefined while for the other scenario, the url wasn't generated and no error was thrown. I have also looked at the express documentation to see if I can store the result of a route in a variable but I didn't see anything like so written.

`carRouter.post('/car', verifyToken, postAdchecker, cloudinaryConfig, multerUploads, postCarAd);`

I want the result of the **upload route** which is the url generated to be passed into another **route(postCarAd)** as a field(imageurl). How do I make that happen?

Comment: No one can help?